# Getting "Default Version" of a Source Artefact in a Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

looking for hopefully some quick help, I have a Release pipeline that deploys a Docker container across 3 environments, the docker container is built fine in a Build Pipeline and a tag is created, the Release Pipeline gets the latest version and I know it successfully gets the latest version I have seen the logs but it's not setting that Tag on the container when it deploys the container to the App service. How do I get the "Default Version" of the source Artefact ?

Add the pic below with the circled value I am trying to find, I did read the documents but I could not work out which value this was everything seemed to be release to Build or Commit version. I've seen the tag in the logs that it gets the correct tag but I don't know which property to use i.e ${Release.Artifacts.{alias}. ?????? }

thanks for any help in advance.

Michael

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Release Pipeline variable: `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildId` to get the version of the Artifacts.

Refer to this doc about [Release Pipeline variables.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch)

> Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildId  The build identifier.

> Azure Pipelines example: 130

Example:

Version:

[image]

Variable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, appreciate it, I'm actually using a classic release pipeline and I'm using the value in the "Tag" property on the AzureAppServiceDeploy, is the format such as this ${Release.Artifacts._dorsavi._alias_.BuildId}

Comment: Got it working turns out on the properties in the class pipeline setting for "Tag" like the image below it need be $(..... not ${ which I think is the format expected in the yaml files. So it was replacing the curly brace with a normal bracket

Comment: Glad to know that it can work. When you use Pipeline variable, you need to follow the format `$(variablename)`. Then it will work.